# MobileFirst platform 8.0 Analytics console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, analytics

How to check page views,visits and unique visitors in Mobile First console?
I want to retrieve detailed data in MFP analytics console like we get in Adobe analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobileFirst Foundation Operational Analytics does not provide anything specific for web apps.

To see things like "page views" you will need to create custom events (based on: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/analytics-api/) and then create charts to view those events (based on: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/analytics/console/custom-charts/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick help..I will check it.